# In BigTable , Whats the best way to read rows with multiple filters (more than two) using condition in JAVA?

Tags: java, filter, google-cloud-bigtable, bigtable

We have a scenario where from UI, the user can send multiple filters in request payload & on the backend data should be read from bigtable adhering to passed filters.
Considering the same example from documentation page :
https://cloud.google.com/bigtable/docs/using-filters#composing-filters

[image]

How can I get all rows with (with all columns or at least some of them mentioned as part of the query object) where "data_plan_05gb = true AND connected_wifi = 1 AND connected_cell = 0 " ?
So far, I have not found even a single example anywhere with multiple filters
Please help me with the above code.
Thank you in advance

i tried with condition :

```
    Filter filter =
        FILTERS
            .condition(
                FILTERS
                    .chain()
                    .filter(FILTERS.qualifier().exactMatch("data_plan_05gb"))
                    .filter(FILTERS.value().exactMatch("true")))
            .then(FILTERS.label("passed-filter"))
            .otherwise(FILTERS.label("filtered-out"));
```

But how can i add further AND conditions like : connected_wifi = 1 AND connected_cell = 0", its not clear